# How to convert column currency(USD and CAD) into one currency?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one column containing "currency(USD and CAD)" and the other one is the currency value.

 How to create a new column that contains converted to USD values?

```
data = {'currency':['CAD', 'USD', 'CAD', 'USD'],'value':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a mapping dict between `USD` and other currencies:

```
rates = {'CAD': 0.7849, 'EUR': 1.1322}
data = {'currency': ['CAD', 'USD', 'CAD', 'EUR'],
        'value': [20, 21, 19, 18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['USD'] = df['currency'].map(rates).fillna(1) * df['value']
print(df)

# Output
  currency  value      USD
0      CAD     20  15.6980
1      USD     21  21.0000
2      CAD     19  14.9131
3      EUR     18  20.3796
```